# Variation of scalar action on a finite volume, boundary terms

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, boundary-conditions, variational-calculus, boundary-terms

My scalar action in $3d$ Euclidean space reads
$$
\mathcal S[\phi,\psi] = \int_V d^3x\, \psi(\vec x)\, \nabla^2\phi(\vec x).
$$
How do you correctly compute its variation with respect to the field $\phi$, if the volume $V$ is finite, and the fields do not vanish at the boundary?

Although I'm interested in the general answer, a simplified version of the question assumes $V$ to be a sphere, and $\phi$ to vanish at the boundary -- but not $\psi$, nor their derivatives.